# Are there any workarounds for the same origin policy iframe issue with no access to the child iframe?

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

I'm wondering if there's any way to listen for an event in a child iframe that I can't modify in any way. I understand that the restriction is the same origin policy. However, I'm wondering about any available workarounds.

Please see an example of what I'd like to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/U7p39/1/